# How print string if she created in function?

Tags: php

The strings `$test1`, `$test2`, `$test3`, and `$test4` are created in the function `test()` . How can I print her?

My code:

**conf.php**

```
<?php
function test(){
    $test1 = 'test1 string';
    $test2 = 'test2 string';
    $test3 = 'test3 string';
    $test4 = 'test4 string';
}
?>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php 
require_once("conf.php");

test();
echo $test1;
echo $test2;
echo $test3;
echo $test4;
?>
```

Why code not worked?

Why weren't `$test1`, `$test2`, `$test3`, and `$test4` printed.

P.S.: preferably without globals parameters.

Comment: *"Why code not worked?"* Because of [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). The name `$test` only exists within the function `test()`. What's wrong with `$test = test(); echo $test`???

Comment: You need to assign the returned value from the function call, or echo it directly

Comment: *"Why code not worked?"* Because `requare_once` is not a function.

Comment: An female string, interesting `:)`

Comment: sorry. i show one element only. me need for 4 strings. see my code again please

Comment: If you want to return more than one value, return an array, eg: `function test() { $test1 = 'value1'; /* etc */ return array($test1, $test2, $test3, $test4); }`, then in test.php do: `list($test1, $test2, $test3, $test4) = test();`

Comment: @DanLee see code again )

Comment: The `$testX` variables only exist *inside* the `test()` function.  You either need to `return` them (as an array), or use `global`s.  Check out the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the multiple entities you have to use arrays.
So, here is a general purpose solution.
For the certain answer we need a certain question though

```
function test() {
    $test[] = 'test1 string';
    $test[] = 'test2 string';
    $test[] = 'test3 string';
    $test[] = 'test4 string';
    return $test;
}


require_once "conf.php";

$test = test();
echo $test[0];
echo $test[1];
echo $test[2];
echo $test[3];
```

Answer (score 1):

You never actually retreive the return value of your `test()` function, this should work:

**conf.php**

```
<?php
function test(){
    $test='test string';
    return $test;
}
?>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php 
    require_once("conf.php");

    $test_value = test();
    echo $test_value;
?>
```

Also, the text is `require_once` not `requare_once`.

Comment: sorry. i show one element only. me need for 4 strings. see my code again please.

Comment: Then do the same, but return an array of strings.
`return array("string1", "string2", "this is string 3", "string4");`

Answer (score 0):

check this way :

```
$test=test();
echo $test;
```

Comment: sorry. i show one element only. me need for 4 strings. see my code again please